# Rotating an object continously in UNITY with onclick

Tags: c#, unity

I have a script that works but it does not do what I want it to do. My script makes an object rotate on when another is clicked. However, I want the object to continuously rotate until I click on the other object again. Right now when I click it rotates just a bit and stops.

Here is my script

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed =50f;
public GameObject target;


public void OnMouseDown(){

    target.transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime, 0) * speed);


}


 }
```

Any assistance? I created what I have now using what I found on the internet but cant find another solution.